# How to generate and download API gateway SDKwith terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, sdk, aws-api-gateway

I want to generate an API Gateway SDK with terraform automatically. Unfortunately, I getting always an error.
I am using following code to generate the SDK:

```
data "aws_api_gateway_sdk" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_stage.example.rest_api_id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.example.stage_name
  sdk_type    = "javascript"
}
```

As an output in the tfstate file I am getting:

```
    {
      "mode": "data",
      "type": "aws_api_gateway_sdk",
      "name": "example",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "body": "PK\u0003\u0004\u..........00",
            "content_disposition": "attachment; filename=\"null-2023-04-18T22:00:16Z-javascript.zip\"",
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "id": "REST_ID:dev:javascript",
            "parameters": null,
            "rest_api_id": "REST_ID",
            "sdk_type": "javascript",
            "stage_name": "dev"
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": []
        }
      ]
    },
```

I tried various ways to extract/save this body file - local-exec, archive_file, local_file, but none of them gave the desired output - a valid sdk zip file on my local filesystem.

Did misunderstood something or what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: What is the error, can you add it to the question?

Comment: When I succeed to create a zip file with one of the methods, it's "corrupt". I can't open it.

Comment: Ah, ok, so you want to have a zip file as a result?

Comment: It actually doesnt has to be a zip file. I just want to store the js files locally or in S3. As the file is generated as a "zip" (according to the content_disposition in the tfstate), i thought i need to store it first as a zip

Answer (score 1):

This provider feature seems to be flawed: it's trying to return the raw content of a `.zip` file as a Terraform string value, but that's impossible because Terraform strings are sequences of unicode characters, not sequences of bytes. `.zip` is a binary format, so it isn't valid to represent the content of such a file as a unicode string.

Therefore I don't think it will be possible to achieve your goal using this data source, until the design of the data source is fixed by the provider development team in a new release. I suggest opening a bug report issue in [the `hashicorp/aws` provider's GitHub repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws).

The typical way for a Terraform provider to return binary content into the Terraform configuration would be to return it as a base64-encoded string. If this data source hypothetically offered another attribute named `body_base64` which included a base64-encoded version of the zip file then you'd be able to write a configuration like this:

```
data "aws_api_gateway_sdk" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_stage.example.rest_api_id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.example.stage_name
  sdk_type    = "javascript"
}

# NOTE: This will not work at the time of writing, because
# the provider does not offer a body_base64 attribute from
# the data source. This is a hypothetical approach that
# could be used if the provider team changes the design
# of the data source to include this attribute.
resource "local_file" "example" {
  filename       = var.sdk_output_filename
  content_base64 = data.aws_api_gateway_sdk.example
}
```

---

However, Terraform isn't really designed for dealing with local files on your system and prefers to only deal with remote API objects. Even if the design of this data source were fixed as I described above, I would not typically expect to be solving this problem within Terraform, and would instead use Terraform only to describe the API, and use a separate process outside of Terraform to generate its SDK.

The fact that this is an unusual problem to solve with Terraform may explain why so far nobody noticed and reported that this data source has a flawed design.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. For now I know that the approach with the local-exec provisioner is a valid, and maybe the only way to automate it with terraform. I already enriched the part to generate, unzip and upload the files to S3 - what my initial idea was. I will also keep in mind to raise a bug report. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I came to a conclusion/workaround.

The approach which I saw on many places didn't work for me.

```
...
data "aws_api_gateway_sdk" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_stage.example.rest_api_id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.example.stage_name
  sdk_type    = "javascript"
}

resource "local_file" "example_sdk" {
  filename = "example_sdk.zip"
  content = data.aws_api_gateway_sdk.example.body
}
...
```

With this approach I am always getting an unusable/corrupted zip file.

What I did instead is to download it with local-exec.

```
resource "null_resource" "extract_sdk" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws apigateway get-sdk --rest-api-id ${aws_api_gateway_stage.example.rest_api_id} --stage-name ${aws_api_gateway_stage.example.stage_name} --sdk-type javascript ./sdk.zip --profile myProfile"
  }
}
```

But to be honest, I don't like this approach because it's kinda "messy", and because someone already thought about the generating of SDKs with terraform and developed *aws_api_gateway_sdk*. And further more, if my credentials are not in the same region as the API gateway, this will not work, so i needed to include the --profile option, to specify the profile.

I would appreciate if someone would tell me where I am wrong and why the "native" terraform solution doesn't work.